# What to use instead of csv2rec

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib.mlab

According to the documentation `matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec` is deprecated, but the message doesn't indicate what we should move to instead. This is an extremely useful function that keeps my scripts short, I don't want to go rewrite all of this by hand. What should I replace this with?

https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec

Comment: There is no alternative within matplotlib. Can you use numpy.genfromtxt, or pandas.read-csv? If not, it might make sense to show your usecase in the question.

Comment: Thanks, `numpy.recfromtxt` seems to do what I want (added in answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get by with the following workaround:

```py
import numpy as np
def csv2rec(filename):
    return np.recfromtxt(filename, dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True, encoding='utf-8')
```